# mysql inner join with nulls in join

Tags: mysql, join

In below sample I expect output id as 1, 4, 6 and 7. But I get only 1, not sure why. By default do we have to use IFNULL for every join in mysql?

```
-- create table
create table t1(col1 int, col2 char(1), col3 varchar(5), col4 date);  
create table t2(col1 int, col2 char(1), col3 varchar(5), col4 date);  

-- insert dummy data
insert into t1 values (1,'m', 'name1', '2000-1-1');  
insert into t2 values (1,'m', 'name1', '2000-1-1');  

insert into t1 values (2,'f', 'name2', '2000-1-1');  
insert into t2 values (2,'f', 'name2', null);  

insert into t1 values (3,'f', null, null);  
insert into t2 values (3,'f', 'name3', null);  

insert into t1 values (4,'f', null, '2000-1-1');  
insert into t2 values (4,'f', null, '2000-1-1');  

insert into t1 values (5,'f', null, '2000-1-1');  
insert into t2 values (5,'f', 'name5', null);  

insert into t1 values (6,'f', null, null);  
insert into t2 values (6,'f', null, null);  

insert into t1 values (7,null, 'name7', '2000-1-1');  
insert into t2 values (7,null, 'name7', '2000-1-1');  

-- select query with inner join  
select a.col1  
from t1 a  
inner join t2 b on b.col2 = a.col2  
and b.col3 = a.col3  
and b.col4 = a.col4
```

Comment: Problem is that u are comparing null. If you really want to get expected result , you should add some string for null value. For eg,if its null auto add its name as "empty" string

Answer (score 5):

`null` can't be matched using `=`.

## Demo

```
mysql> SELECT null = null, null <=> null;
+-------------+---------------+
| null = null | null <=> null |
+-------------+---------------+
|        NULL |             1 |
+-------------+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

You can use `<=>` to replace `=`.

```
select a.col1
from t1 a
inner join t2 b on b.col1 <=> a.col1
and b.col2 <=> a.col2
and b.col3 <=> a.col3
and b.col4 <=> a.col4;
```

Comment: Using your above query I get 1, 3, 4, 5, 6 and 7. Col3 for row id 3 doesnt match, so why do I get 3? same goes with id 5.

Comment: `(3,'f', null, null)` matches `(6,'f', null, null)`. this is as expected.

Comment: Thanks got it, i got the desired resutl set by adding col1 to the join

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
SELECT 
    t1.col1,
    t1.col2,
    t1.col3,
    t1.col4
FROM 
    t1 
INNER JOIN t2 
ON (
    ( (t1.col1 = t2.col1)  OR ( t1.col1 is null && t2.col1 is null) ) AND
    ( (t1.col2 = t2.col2)  OR ( t1.col2 is null && t2.col2 is null) ) AND
    ( (t1.col3 = t2.col3)  OR ( t1.col3 is null && t2.col3 is null) ) AND
    ( (t1.col4 = t2.col4)  OR ( t1.col4 is null && t2.col4 is null) ) 
)
```

Comment: If you think it worked then reward it.So it will be better for other user.@Ali

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be as per below-

```
select a.col1
from t1 a
inner join t2 b on a.col1=b.col1 
and b.col2 <=> a.col2
and b.col3 <=> a.col3
and b.col4 <=> a.col4;
```

sql fiddle is here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/62b77f/8

Note: If you don't join col1 then col1 will match with all columns of other table, so you will get extra rows than you expected.

Comment: This answer could include a note that the **`<=>`** (spaceship) operator is  a MySQL-specific operator that performs a "null safe equality" comparison. A normal equality comparison returns a NULL if either of the values being compared are NULL. Reference: [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to)